# Change starting point, scale in ggvis for R

Tags: r, ggvis, rescale

I am trying to create a line graph but I want to change the `y-axis` scale that it goes from `0 - 0.5` and another one where it goes from `0 - 1`. Whenever I use the "values" argument it is not getting me the graph I wanted. This is my current code:

```
lnHFbyCirclePer %>%
    ggvis(~TimePoint, ~CirclePercentage, stroke = ~lnHF_SPLIT) %>%
    layer_lines() %>% 
    layer_paths(data = lnHFbyStarPer,x = ~TimePoint, y = ~StarPercentage,   stroke = ~lnHF_SPLIT, strokeDash := 6) %>% 
    add_axis("y", title = "Percentage of Deck Chosen") %>%
    add_axis("x", title = "Time Point", orient = "bottom")
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with `dput(lnHFbyCirclePer)` ?

Comment: No worries. I learned it could be easily done with the scale_numeric("y", domain = c(range)) function.

Comment: @Ravi Post that as an answer please and accept. It might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. I learned it could be easily done with the "scale_numeric("y", domain = c(range))" function.